# Z-index overlapping issue in Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, z-index

On my website i have set z-index: 1000 for an image when the hover state is active, which works great in firefox, but it doesn't in chrome.

Please check the gifs: the enlarged image shows up behind the text, even if the text z-index is lower then 1000. [This is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfuKx.gif) and this is what i am trying to archive: [showing the image on hover above the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kotqy.gif)

My website is https://pixelbeast.hu

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: you need to look at your code again as the one in chrome the first one is your issue but the bottom one is fine. So console why that works....this is for future ref...but the answer is **you are missing `z-index:1000` on the first image container**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add `position: relative;` style rule to your image to make `z-index: 1000;` works.

`z-index` only works on **positioned elements** (`position:absolute`, `position:relative`, or `position:fixed`).